# how do I fix PEP fields.E339 in django models through/through_fields?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to link vulnerability cve models with products via intermediate models to link/match each vulnerability based on the product / cve

```
class Vulnerability(models.Model):
    cveid = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True)
    affected_products = models.ManyToManyField(
        Product,
        through='ProductVulnerability',
        through_fields=("product", "vulnerability")
    )


class ProductVulnerability(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vulnerability = models.ForeignKey(Vulnerability, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    class Meta:
        unique_together = [("product", "vulnerability")]
```

```
service         | ERRORS:
service         | api.Vulnerability.affected_products: (fields.E339) 'ProductVulnerability.product' is not a foreign key to 'Vulnerability'.
service         |   HINT: Did you mean one of the following foreign keys to 'Vulnerability': vulnerability?
service         | api.Vulnerability.affected_products: (fields.E339) 'ProductVulnerability.vulnerability' is not a foreign key to 'Product'.
service         |   HINT: Did you mean one of the following foreign keys to 'Product': product?
service         | SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:
```

Answer (score 2):

As [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through_fields) and as HINT would suggest

> through_fields accepts a 2-tuple ('field1', 'field2'), where field1 is
> the name of the foreign key to the model the ManyToManyField is
> defined on , and field2 the name of the foreign
> key to the target model.

so in your case

```
affected_products = models.ManyToManyField(
    Product,
    through='ProductVulnerability',
    through_fields=("vulnerability", "product")
)
```